# Error de optimización de compilación

Tags: build, yarn

Error de optimización de compilación: página encontrada sin un componente de React como exportación predeterminada en pages/theme

Que al momento de hacer yarn build Me sale el error: Build optimization                   failed: found page without a React Component as default export in pages/theme

El archivo tiene extensión js

Y no encuentro que es lo qué hay que agregarle

Tengo este archivo

```
    import { createTheme }  
    from '@mui/material';
    const theme =     
    createTheme({
    palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#0072ce',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: 'rgb(255, 136, 
    type here
     26, 1)',
    },
  },
    typography: {
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
  },
  });

   export default theme
```

Comment: Si el archivo tiene extension `.jsx`, cambialo a `js`. Puede que este comprobando que los `export default` de los `.jsx` sean componentes, y en tu caso no lo es.

Comment: Tiene extensión js

Comment: Entonces prueba cambiando `export default theme` por `export theme`. Luego cuando lo importes, lo haces como `import { theme } from './pages/theme'`.

Comment: si quito el dafult, me da un error de Parsing error: Unexpected token theme